# how to create content in refcards (like dzone)

Tags: graphics

Many of us have used refcards. I have seen many from Dzone.

How to create content/refcards like those(effectively space utilized graphic and text) for my own purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create infographics using these online tools:

http://www.easel.ly/

https://infogr.am/